# Кто такая цаца?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

"Ишь какая цаца!" — так говорят о надменном, слишком много о себе мнящем человеке.
Но вот кто такая эта "цаца"? Раньше я думала, что речь об украшении оклада иконы, но оно, как выяснилось, называется "цата".
Или же здесь просто какое-то звукоподражательство, не имеющее конкретного аналога в речи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А. И. Сахаров в своей работе отметил два значения слова цаца: 1) игрушка; 2) недотрога.

Это слово — явное звукоподражание. По-видимому, возникло оно в детском языке. Даль признавал даже в 50—60-х годах это слово областным. В «Толковом словаре» Даля находим: «Цаца, ж. или цяця, цацка, юж. зап. кал. тмб. `детская игрушка';`украса, прикраса'; // `послушный ребеночек'» (сл. Даля 1882, 4, с. 588).

С литературным языком слово цаца сблизилось в 30-е годы XIX в. Его пустил в литературный язык тогдашний модный писатель Н. В. Кукольник. В его драматической фантазии «Джулио Мости» (СПб., 1830) есть песенка, сопровождающая пляску Доменико Зампиери. Тут встречается слово цаца:

*Цаца! не пиши пером!

Ляля! не играй смычком!*

В примечаниях к пьесе Кукольник пишет об этих словах: «Многие спрашивали у меня, что значат эти два слова [цаца и ляля. — В. В.]. В ребячестве я приветствовал и ласкал ими мои игрушки. Привычка и память детства ввели их в мой словарь. Да простит читатель воспоминаниям нежного возраста».

В русском литературном языке областные значения слова цаца — `игрушка, украшение, резьба на дереве' не укрепились. На основе экспрессивного ласкательного значения этого слова — применительно к детям — развилось в разговорно-фамильярной речи экспрессивное употребление слова цаца для выражения любовного отношения к тому, кто является предметом обожания, забот, любви, внимания, ухода. Например, у П. Д. Боборыкина в романе «Василий Теркин»: «презреннее всех — Теркин, ее идол, ее цаца, променявший такую любовь, такую женщину на что и на кого?» (Боборыкин 1895, с. 496).

От него -  "цацкаться с кем-либо - слишком ухаживать за кем-нибудь, носиться, возиться".  Позднее — в 70-х годах в разговорно-фамильярной речи установилось употребление слова цацас экспрессией легкого пренебрежения применительно к тому, кто слишком важничает, кто слишком носится с собой, предъявляет слишком много претензий (Что ты за цаца такая?). По-моему, тоже связано с детством - как капризный ребёнок.
http://wordhist.narod.ru/caca.html

Comment: С детства помню строчки Вл.Маяковского : "Это — зебра.

Ну и цаца!

 Полосатее матраца. " (Стихи для детей - Вл.Маяковский . "Что ни страница , - то слон , то львица ." )

Answer (score 1):

В белорусском языке по сей день игрушки - **цацки**. Надо отметить, что именно этот язык сохранил очень много старорусских слов и донёс их до наших дней практически без искажения. Ну а происхождение этого слова явно звукоподражательное, ибо, играя (цацкаясь) с малышом, мы зачастую издаём звуки, похожие на слог "ца", цокая языком.